# Alternative chmod for git hook in Windows 7

Tags: windows, git, command-line

I am trying to activate one git hook under Windows 7, but I don´t find the alternative to chmod +x post-commit (in my case) in this operating system, with Unix is working correctly

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `chmod` needed.

Just call the file `post-commit` and you're done.

If you have for example a perl file, you'll need a shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

Comment: Thank you @eckes for your response and help.. I have written a file called post-commit, and in the inside `git push origin master` and the next line with the path to the python file,  what should it be the extension?